# Changing the data type "varchar'' of a column to "DATE" in SQL/ORACLE

Tags: sql, date, oracle10g, database

I have a table in a database created in oracle 10G. It contains a column of type 'VARCHAR' and stores date as string in this format->  'dd-mon-yyyy' eg: '12-aug-2008'. Now I want to change the datatype of this column from VARCHAR to [DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413). but when i perfrom this query->

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order
MODIFY COLUMN delivery_date DATE;
```

I get following error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

I have also tried :

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order
ALTER COLUMN delivery_date DATE;
```

I got the error :

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

However when i try to add a fresh column with DATE datatype it works fine. 
example :

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order
ADD delivery DATE;
```

So, can anybody suggest me a way to change the datatype without deleting the column and its data.

Answer (score 5):

It's the first one, with a slight modification:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order MODIFY (delivery_date DATE);
```

But I'm not *sure* that will work for those particular datatypes and it also may not work depending on the current data.

You may find it necessary in that case to:

- create a new column `X` of date type.
- populate `X` based on the old column (may need several passes of data fix-ups to work).
- delete old column.
- rename `X` to old column name.

Comment: The keyword `column` is optional and then the parentheses are as well. `ALTER TABLE sales_order MODIFY delivery_date DATE` would be correct syntax as well. But changing from `varchar` to `date` will result in an `ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name I agree with you, that means i have to follow the steps suggested by paxdiablo. I also figured it out that in conversion of data types which are incompatible or if we are reducing precision (eg : float to int), it gives error `column must be empty.`

Answer (score 2):

Although its a pretty old question, I'll put my solution here for people seeking for a solution:

Here's my solution and it works perfectly.

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_order` CHANGE `delivery_date` `delivery_date` DATE;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

modify a column then syntax is:-

**alter table table_name modify column_name datatype;**

but when you modify the column datatype column must be empty

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints!  This got it for me.

alter table Table_Name 
Alter column Column_Name datatype
GO

I too was needing to change from a VARCHAR to a date.  I am working in SQL 2008 R2. I have found that if I bring in dates as a char or varchar and then change the type to date or datetime, I can catch time/date problems more easily.

THIS STATEMENT WILL FAIL IF YOUR DATA HAS ANY BAD DATES. (I break the date down into sections to find the bad date so I can correct and then I can alter the column type.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create a new column, in which the data type is DATE. then pass the data in your varchar as a date .then drop your initial column and finally rename your new column to what it was initially...code below.

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (new_col DATE);
UPDATE my_table SET new_col=TO_DATE(old_col,'MM/DD/YYYY');
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP (old_col);
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN new_col TO old_col;
```

Answer (score 0):

alter table employee add (DOB varchar(10));
if you add a column with datatype varchar and if you want to modify the datatype of DOB then you can use this command ->
alter table employee modify(DOB date);
Now the table is modified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).